# Dokku: setuidgid: fatal: unable to run gunicorn: file does not exist

Tags: python, django, dokku

I am trying to run my application in [Dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku)

I get this error:

```
5b188e740fcae5a5080e2ac498e6b93a593ae107e656c53e5df1d8c8e13948c8
remote:  !     App container failed to start!!
=====> lala web container output:
       setuidgid: fatal: unable to run gunicorn: file does not exist
       setuidgid: fatal: unable to run gunicorn: file does not exist
       setuidgid: fatal: unable to run gunicorn: file does not exist
       setuidgid: fatal: unable to run gunicorn: file does not exist
       setuidgid: fatal: unable to run gunicorn: file does not exist
       setuidgid: fatal: unable to run gunicorn: file does not exist
       setuidgid: fatal: unable to run gunicorn: file does not exist
=====> end lala web container output
remote: 2020/12/17 23:22:13 exit status 1
remote: 2020/12/17 23:22:13 exit status 1
remote: 2020/12/17 23:22:13 exit status 1
To coffee-and-sugar.club:lala
 ! [remote rejected] main -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess you have a `Procfile` like this:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application
```

I need to install the python package first.

Add `gunicorn` to your `requirements.txt` file.